# How to get the product count without using lambda expressions?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a table products:

```
product_id
product_name
prodcut_price
```

My dbcontext name is `abcentity`.

I want to get how many number of products (like products count) along with `product_id`,`product_name`,`product_price`.

I have done using lambda expressions using `Groupby product_id` (this is for Linq to Sql, but I am using linq to entity).

I don't want to use lambda expressions. Is it possible to get the product count without using lambda expressions?

Comment: Why don't you want to use lambda expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you just trying to avoid lambda syntax? You can use the `group by` clause in LINQ query expression syntax instead of calling `.GroupBy()`.

```
from p in abcentity.products
group p by p.product_id into g
select new {g.Key, g.Count()}
```

But I should point out that this still gets compiled as a lambda expression. All you're changing is the syntax you use to represent it.

Comment: can i get product_price and product_name same like g.count,g.key ???  would you pls reply..

Comment: @user: You can change `select new {g.Key, g.Count()}` to `select new {g.Key, g.Count(), g.FirstOrDefault().product_price, g.FirstOrDefault().product_name, }`. Keep in mind that the query I provided will only have 1 product for each product ID if your product IDs are identity keys. Is there something else you intended to group by, or can there be multiple `product`s in your table with the same `product_id`?

Comment: @user: Sheesh, dude, have a little patience. You only need to ask once. And one question mark or period at a time, please.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Linq to SQL by default, then no. The `Expression` that is created from making the lambda is what is used to determine the query to create.

If you want a custom expression, you can execute any SQL you define - Scott Gu blogged about how to do this [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/27/linq-to-sql-part-8-executing-custom-sql-expressions.aspx).

If that is not what you want to do, then perhaps you can explain why you don't want to use lambda expressions?

Comment: I am not using linq to sql , As i have mentioned in question i am using linq to entities.... so is it possible to get the count using only linq to entities....